# Wordpress audio player only playing first attached file

Tags: wordpress, audio

I have a table with play and stop buttons that plays the attached audio file on the post using Custom Fields plugin. My custom field is called *preview*. I have created a shortcode using Wordpress default audio shortcode. I can get the audio player to show, but when I click play it plays the first attached file from the website, but when I click any of my play buttons it won't play on the audio player.

See attached picture.

[image]

This is the code I came up with

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[audio mp3='". $id . '" data-audio="' . $url . '" data-swf="' . $plugin_url . '/assets/js/jquery.jplayer/Jplayer.swf' ."']"); ?>
```

Comment: You'll need to post more information. But my suspicion is that when you click on the different play buttons the $id and or the $url aren't changing in response

Comment: You are correct, the $id or $url aren't changing in response and that's what I need it to do, I've been trying to figure this out and no luck. My point with this is that I need to show a progress/seek bar so customers can skip through the playing track and not sit there waiting to hear the whole track with only having the play buttons on the table.

Comment: You'll have to post more of your code. To do what you want, you'll need to do it client side (so outside of PHP), and depending on what kind of client side javascript library you're using there are different possibilities